# How to download a file after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I automatically download a file after an AJAX call? Now my AJAX call is redirecting me to the resource, but not downloading the file.

this is my AJAX call:

```
$('.download').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let videoId = $('#video').data('video-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/video/" + videoId + "/download-link",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            window.location = response.link;
        }
    });

});
```

And this is the html tag:

```
<a href="#" class="download">
     <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i>Download
</a>
```

Comment: what you get after clicking on download link?

Comment: a redirect to the file url

Comment: show your php code?

Comment: php code returns an URL, there's nothing wrong there

Answer (score 1):

because you are redirecting it manually via `window.location`. There are multiple ways to download file if you have resource link. One of them is to use `download` attribute .( Also You can always try to search if same question exists already before posting it as new question). 
 You can find detailed answer here :
[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is make sure that the server responds with the following header for the file url

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file-name" // file name is not required, and can be ommitted
// This will make browsers understand that this is a downloadable resource
```

and then in your ajax do this

```
...
window.open(response.link, '_blank');
```